# Is there a way to add more information to a node, except the mandatory ones?

Tags: corda

I want to add more node information to a network node. Is it possible to share more data besides what's in the node configuration file? Maybe some custom fields, like an encoded logo image or stuff like that.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of information? and what is it for?

Comment: Information readable by another node in the network. Like the default O, L, C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes you can.
2. Inside your module under `src` folder add a file called `config.conf`.
3. Add your values inside of it in the following format:

```
key1="string_value"
key2=number_value
```

4. Inside `build.gradle` go to the part where you define your nodes, let's say your module name is "my_module"; do this:

```
cordapp (project(':my_module')) {   
    config project.file("src/config.conf")
}
```

5. Now when you run `deployNodes`, gradle will generate a file called `my_module.conf` under `build\nodes\my_node\cordapps\config`.
6. To access those values inside your flow:

```
getServiceHub().getAppContext().getConfig().getString("key1");
```

7. As for testing flows; to mimic the custom config file you need to do the following:

```
Map<String, String> customConfig = new HashMap<>();
customConfig.put("key1", "string_value");
customConfig.put("key2", "int_value");

// Setup network.
network = new MockNetwork(new MockNetworkParameters().withCordappsForAllNodes(ImmutableList.of(
        TestCordapp.findCordapp("my_package").withConfig(customConfig))));
```

Comment: Hi Adel, 

Thanks for the answer.

Would this information be readable by other nodes in the network, like the O,L,C fields?

Comment: Not unless you write a flow pair (initiator / responder) where the initiator requests that info from the responder.

Comment: Can you detail a bit on this? I am very new to corda. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you read about flows (initiating / responder); in short, Node-A will initiate a flow which will build a session to connect to Node-B, Node-A will send to Node-B the requested information, Node-B will have a flow that is registered to respond to the initiating flow of Node-A, inside the responder; Node-B will fetch the information from the custom config and send it to Node-A.

Comment: I formatted my answer into a short Medium article: https://blog.b9lab.com/how-to-create-a-cordapp-configuration-file-ef79581b9e3-ef79581b9e3c