# Unable to make a Corda Testnet node issuable

Tags: corda

I've successfully set up a Corda Open Source 4.3 Testnet node, and I can connect with the Node Explorer. However I'm having difficulty figuring out instructions 3 and 4 found here: https://docs.corda.net/head/testnet-explorer-corda.html

Considering the finance CorDapp has been split into 2 CorDapps, I have copied both of the jar files downloaded in step 3 into /opt/corda/cordapps, before trying step 4 and eventually running the node. Having done that I connected with the Node Explorer and found that I could only select "pay" in the new transaction modal. I have also tried creating 2 matching conf files for each of the CorDapps, with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instruction #4 is not correct, the configuration file name must match the name of your CorDapp, so if your CorDapp jar is `MyCorDapp.jar` then the config file would be the same name but with `.conf` extension instead (i.e. `MyCorDapp.conf`).
So in your case you should have 2 conf files (one for workflows and one for contracts) with the same content:
- `corda-finance-contracts-4.3-SNAPSHOT.conf`
- `corda-finance-workflows-4.3-SNAPSHOT.conf`

Comment: More info on the topic of custom configuration files (like the one used in Finance CorDapp): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609748/is-there-a-way-to-add-more-information-to-a-node-except-the-mandatory-ones/58696519#58696519