# Suppress oracle calls in unit test of corda flows

Tags: unit-testing, corda

I have a corda flow which invokes oracle node and it further tries to hit an external resource using secured channel. I need to mock oracle node or suppress the call to external resource and want it to provide mock data for unit tests. What should be the correct approach for it? How can I inject values into the flow?

Comment: I never used Oracles, but in my flow I make an http call and the URL of that call is stored in a custom CorDapp configuration file; so in my flow test I set the URL to a local resource (e.g. localhost), while on GCP (Google Cloud) I set the URL to the real one. Maybe you can adapt the same approach for your Oracle?

If that approach is doable in your case, I answered in detail here about how to use custom configuration files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609748/is-there-a-way-to-add-more-information-to-a-node-except-the-mandatory-ones/58696519#58696519

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this sample to create a mock oracle service to test your cordapp: https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/oracle-example